# How can I make web resources avialable offline?

Tags: linux, apache, web, caching

Their is a folder in my PC with Linux OS, which contains a website (webpages etc.). The webpages and other complimentary files in the folder use cdns to bring resources like jquery, datatables etc.

I want to make these resources offline. I know I can manually search all files for occurrence of "http" keyword, download files from these URLs keep them in folder and accordingly change source file path. But as these are too many files it seems troublesome. I want to ask is there any better and elegant way of doing so. Thanks in advance

Comment: Most browsers offer a feature to "download a site" or similar. They create an archive of the resources. Maybe that is a starting point for you.

Comment: Apart from that: such resources should actually get cached on your client site so that they are indeed loaded just once from the server, whether it is a CDN or not.

Comment: @arkascha I think there is a misunderstanding, what I mean is that how can I make resources offline on server not on client side.

Comment: Then you will have to explain a bit more what you are actually trying to do. To "make a server offline" is nothing that does make much sense from a technological point of view. So it would help if you would explain what you actually want to achieve instead of using such terminologies like "make offline". A server is something that serves resources over a network. That does not go will with "offline", obviously. So what is it you actually have in mind? How should thise resources be used by clients? Where should they come from?

Comment: @arkascha Sorry about miscommunication. What I mean is that earlier I had made a website in a server which had access to internet, back then I had used cdns for obtain resources. But now I want to make server access only local resources over intranet, but doing so will cause the route to cdn break thus causing website to break. I can manually search all files for occurrence of "http" keyword, download files from these URLs keep them in folder and accordingly change source file path.

Comment: I still have problems to understand. You still write you want to make "server access only local resources over intranet" ... Really the server or the client that displays that "website"? Or is that server actually within the local network and you want to enable it to serve the whole page, including resources stored in that CDN nodes only from the local network?

Comment: @arkascha I guess word "resources" is causing confusion. I mean by "resources" elements like jquery, datatables etc.. Earlier server had access to internet so it can fetch these resources from internet, but now I want to disable server from accessing internet i.e. "enable it to serve the whole page, including resources stored in that CDN nodes only from the local network".

Comment: OK, so let's drop the term "offline" from your description and say "from within the local network" instead. Then things start to make sense. And also don't speak of "folders", but of content served by a server you operate in that local network.

Comment: I want to point out two options you have: 1. you could certainly try to use the "substitution" module that for example the apache http server offers to replace references to the CDN by local references. But I doubt that is a good idea, it is neither easy nor efficient. Instead why don't you simply take a IDE, open the project that contains those local files that hold the references to the CDN. That way finding the references is trivial and you can quickly change the m one by one, potentially even by using a "search and replace" tool inside the IDE. Takes less time than you would expect.

Comment: Take care to use relative links this time. Those are easier to handle in most situation. Even if you want to move the resources to some other server later you could easily implement that by means of a proxy rule inside your server. So without having to touch the files holding the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a python script to do the job:

```
import re
import os
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import pathlib
import string
import random

import chardet

# Decode byte sequence using chardet to avoid "Type error"
def decode_bytes(byte_sequence):
    result = chardet.detect(byte_sequence)
    encoding = result['encoding']
    return byte_sequence.decode(encoding)

VALID_URL_REGEX = re.compile(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')

# Downloader, I lazily have used resp.status as success criteria but it have logical issue you can also include other logic
async def download_file(session, url, local_path):
    async with session.get(url, allow_redirects=True, ssl=False) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            print("Content path is "+str(local_path))
            with open(local_path, "wb") as f:
                while True:
                    print(local_path)
                    chunk = await resp.content.read(4196)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    chunk = chunk.encode("utf-8")
                    f.write(chunk)
downloaded_urls = set()
async def process_file(file_path, session):
    print("File during Read "+str(file_path))
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        try:
            contents = decode_bytes(contents)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            # To avoid Type error
            print(f"Error decoding file {file_path}: {e}")
            return
        urls = re.findall(VALID_URL_REGEX, contents)
        try:
            for url in urls:
                file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
                if len(file_name)==0:
                    continue
                if url in downloaded_urls:
                    local_path = downloaded_urls[url]
                # generating random strings to avoid same file name but different urls
                res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase +string.digits, k=5))
                file_name=res+file_name
                local_path = os.path.join("downloaded", file_name)
                if not os.path.exists(local_path):
                    await download_file(session, url, local_path)
                    # To avoid redownloading
                    downloaded_urls.add(url)
                contents = contents.replace(url, local_path)
        except:
            pass
    print("File during write "+str(file_path))
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
        f.write(contents)

async def process_directory(directory):
    
        if not os.path.exists("downloaded"):
            os.makedirs("downloaded")
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=2200,limit_per_host=20,ttl_dns_cache=22)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
            tasks = []
            try:
                for filepath in pathlib.Path(directory).glob('**/*'):
                    fp=filepath.absolute()
                    if str(fp).endswith(".md") or str(fp).endswith(".txt"):
                        continue
                    if os.path.isfile(fp):
                        tasks.append(process_file(fp, session))
            except:
                pass
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = input("Enter root directory")           asyncio.run(process_directory(directory))
```

I will also try "substitution" module and update answer accordingly.